# Qual a diferença percentual entre o número de endereços possíveis com IPv4 e IPv6?

Tags: ip, ipv4, ipv6

Qual é a diferença em números percentuais das possibilidades de ip do `IPv4` e do `IPv6`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conforme já falado, o `IPV6` utiliza endereços de 128bits e possui, portanto, 2<sup>128</sup> números de `IP` possíveis, ou seja:

> **340282366920938463463374607431768211456** combinações possíveis.
>
> (340 undecilhões 282 decilhões 366 nonilhões 920 octilhões 938 setilhões 463 sextilhões 463 quintilhões 374 quatrilhões 607 trilhões 431 bilhões 768 milhões 211 mil 456 )

Enquanto o `IPV4` utiliza endereços de 32bits e possui 2<sup>32</sup> números de `IP` possíveis, que corresponde a:

> **4294967296** combinações possíveis
>
> (4 bilhões 294 milhões 967 mil 296)

Ou seja, é um número muito, muito, muito alto.

Enquanto que no modelo `IPV4` temos algo semelhante a isto:

> **192.168.0.1**
>   4 grupos com até 3 algarismos decimais.

Logo, para cada conjunto de 3 algarismos temos:

> 2<sup>8</sup> * 2<sup>8</sup> * 2<sup>8</sup> * 2<sup>8</sup> = **2<sup>32</sup>**
>   pois 2<sup>8</sup> = 256.
>   **2<sup>32</sup>** = **4294967296**

No `IPV6` temos o `IP` desta maneira:

> **2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344**
>   Oito grupos de 4 dígitos hexadecimais.

Essa diferença na notação possibilitou um *range* maior de possibilidades, que pode ser calculada dessa forma:

> (2<sup>16</sup> * 2<sup>16</sup> * 2<sup>16</sup> * 2<sup>16</sup> * 2<sup>16</sup> * 2<sup>16</sup> * 2<sup>16</sup> * 2<sup>16</sup>) = **2<sup>128</sup>**
>   pois os algarismos hexadecimais compreende 16 valores de 0 a 9 e de A a F 
>   então, **2<sup>128</sup>** corresponde aos **340282366920938463463374607431768211456** já mencionados.

Com uma regra de 3 simples temos que:

> 2<sup>128</sup> = 100%
>   2<sup>32</sup> = x
>
> 2<sup>128</sup>x = 2<sup>32</sup>
>
> x = 2<sup>32</sup> / 2<sup>128</sup>
>
> x = 1/79228162514264337593543950336
>   Ou seja, o `IPV6` é **79.228.162.514.264.337.593.543.950.336%** maior que o `IPV4`
>   E o `IPV4` possui:
>
> **1.262177448353618888658765704452457967477130296174436807... × 10<sup>-29</sup>%** dos endereços do `IPV6`

#### **Fontes**

1. [https://www.wolframalpha.cominput?i=%282^16+*+2^16+*+2^16+*+2^16+*+2^16+*+2^16+*+2^16+*+2^16%29](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E16%20%2a%202%5E16%20%2a%202%5E16%20%2a%202%5E16%20%2a%202%5E16%20%2a%202%5E16%20%2a%202%5E16%20%2a%202%5E16%29)
2. [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282^8+*+2^8+*+2^8+*+2^8%29](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E8%20%2a%202%5E8%20%2a%202%5E8%20%2a%202%5E8%29)
3. [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282^32%29+%2F+%282^128%29](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E32%29%20/%20%282%5E128%29)

Comment: Esta é a resposta correta, a minha arredonda o 79.228...

Answer (score 8):

Tradução livre de [conteúdo da Wikipedia em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6):

> O IPv6 usa endereços de 128 bits, permitindo 2<sup>128</sup> ou 3.4×10<sup>38</sup> endereços, ou seja, mais de 7.9×10<sup>28</sup> vezes mais que o IPv4.

Isso significa, conforme os comentários postados abaixo por @Vargas e @tsippert:

- IPV6 é **79.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000%** maior que o IPV4
- IPv4 tem apenas **0.0000000000000000000000000012632257%** dos endereços do IPv6

Comment: Considerando que os valores do @bfavaretto estão corretos então, IPV6 é 79.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000% maior que o IPV4.

Comment: @Vargas Boa, não tive paciência pra ficar contando zeros ao digitar :)

Comment: Atualizei o valor, meu cálculo anterior estava errado ;)

Comment: Quando vi IPV4 e 0000...% Li IPVA

Comment: @Tony Se o IPVA fosse barato assim seria bom.

Answer (score 3):

IPV4 tem 32 bits, IPV6 tem 128 bits.

É um valor tão absurdamente grande, que é possível dizer que o IPV4 = 0% do IPV6